# Is there any possible way to automute ads on YouTube?

Tags: internet, browser, flash, youtube, html5

This is probably going to be very difficult because YouTube uses both a flash player and a HTML5 player, but is there any possible way to make sure that when ads are being played, the volume is muted, and when the actual video is playing, the volume is unmuted?

I would prefer to not block the ads.

Comment: why do you prefer not block the ads?

Comment: @Chin: Because I am OK with ads and would like to support the content maker. I don't like ads when they start playing audio especially on websites with no audio.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use an ad-block type of technique, but where you **filter the ads' sounds**, instead of blocking them alltogether. As for the how, I recently read a question about muting audio streams...

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome, there is an extension called [YouMute(r)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youmuter/hbhjkldledabllijjmnmfhhiejephibe) which mutes the YouTube player when ads are playing. When the ad finishes, the player is unmuted.

[The source code is on GitHub](https://github.com/adamgajzlerowicz/muter)